# CCSprite Image Turns to Black when launching from background

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The following image shows the problem.
When I launch my app from background after a while, I found some CCsprites on the CCScene turns to black.
I have no idea about the reason(I guess it related to memory?). 
Any suggestion?

PS. All the code is running on the main thread, so there should be no thread issues

[image: Result Pict]

Comment: remove derive data and clean and build your projrct

Comment: @AlienArrays the biggest 2x png consumes about 74 kb. And it will only happen when I launch from background. Feel strange, too. : (

Comment: @KiritModi nope, after I set my app into background & launch several times, the problem happens

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/manually-creating-pixel-data-for-a-cctexture2d-results-in-a-black-sprite/

Comment: strange issue you change format of image .png to .jpg

Comment: Is it possible you are receiving a notification from the OS to dump some memory and the cache has been emptied (partially) because of this?  Can you set up a counter that gets incremented in applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning and see if it is going up when you wake up and this has occurred?

Comment: Does this happen on the device and the simulator?

Comment: @Tiddly Happened on the device